# How many scrolls can I have deciphered at once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

My sorcerer has 4 CL 3 scrolls of Fireball.  I know that he cannot use them before deciphering them and this can be done in advance.

Can he decipher all of them before a battle?  How long before he would need to decipher them again?

Comment: [More about scroll deciphering.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26922/8610)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, CL 3 scroll of fireball is a very strange occurence, since the scroll [can not be written at a caster level lower than a minimum required to cast a spell in question](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/scrolls.html), which is CL 5 for a 3rd level sor/wiz spell.

Second, deciphering the scroll [is a full-round action which can very well be done in advance.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/scrolls.html)

> *Decipher the Writing*: The writing on a scroll must be deciphered before a character can use it or know exactly what spell it contains. This requires a read magic spell or a successful Spellcraft check (DC 20 + spell level). Deciphering a scroll is a full-round action.

Third, [you only ever need to decipher a given scroll once](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/scrolls.html):

> A character can decipher the writing on a scroll in advance so that she can proceed directly to the next step when the time comes to use the scroll.

Comment: I understand that level 5 (wiz) or 6 (sorcerer) is required to craft, but the crafter can choose make the scroll at the minimum CL of the spell, correct?

Comment: @DavidWilkins correct, but the minimum caster level for a fireball (3rd level spell) is 5. You may want to visit the links, they say exactly that.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for clarifying even though it wasn't part of the original question.  :)

Comment: Also - just because it was explicitly called out in the title of the question - there is no limit to the number of scrolls a character can decipher. Well, presumably they'll die of old age or run out of scrolls at some point, but they can keep on increasing the number deciphered until that point.